# QGraphicsTextItem. можно ли определить координаты , ширину и длину элемента?

Tags: c++, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

у меня есть на сцене разные элементы. прямые линии, "пользовательский элемент" , это я сделал у наследовавшись QGraphicsItem. а так же QGraphicsTextItem.

Скажите реально ли получить координату верхнего угла этого QGraphicsTextItem, а так же высоту и ширину  ?

Вот при помощи QGraphicsItem который соответствует моему QGraphicsTextItem, я воспользовался pos(), но координата получается неправильной, а определить ширину, высоту вообще не понимаю как. реально ли вообще это сделать ?